# How to use ax with Pandas and Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matplotlib

I have a very basic question. I am using a pandas dataframe to make this plot, but I want to add highlighting around certain dates.

```
In[122]:
df1_99.plot(x='date', y='units', ylim=[0,11], figsize=[12,12])
```

Out[122]:
[image]

I found this code on stackoverflow to add highlighting.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot_date(t, y, 'b-')
ax.axvspan(*mdates.datestr2num(['10/27/2011', '11/2/2011']), color='red', alpha=0.5)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

My question is how can I use ax.avxspan with my current code? Or do I need to convert my x='date', and y='units' to numpy arrays and use the format as in the code above?

Comment: `df.plot` returns an AxesSubplot, which has a `axvspan` method.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) will return the matplotlib `AxesSubplot` object.

```
ax = df1_99.plot(x='date', y='units', ylim=[0,11], figsize=[12,12])

ax.axvspan(*mdates.datestr2num(['10/27/2011', '11/2/2011']), color='red', alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

If you want to create an `ax` object in advance, you can pass it into `plot` as below

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df1_99.plot(x='date', y='units', ylim=[0,11], figsize=[12,12], ax=ax)

ax.axvspan(*mdates.datestr2num(['10/27/2011', '11/2/2011']), color='red', alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Finally, you can usually get the current figure and axes objects using [the following functions](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.gca)

```
fig = plt.gcf()
ax = plt.gca()
```

Comment: Ok that makes a lot more sense now. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have been looking for a way to use Matplotlib figure methods on plots made with pandas. The fig, ax = plt.subplots() and then plotting with ax=ax gave the link I needed. Thank you!