# Understanding of fig, ax, and plt when combining Matplotlib and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to get a better understanding of how figure, axes, and plt all fit together when combining Matplotlib and Pandas for plotting. The accepted [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29568110/how-to-use-ax-with-pandas-and-matplotlib/29568196#29568196) helped me connect Matplotlib and Pandas in an object oriented way I understand through this line:

```
fig, ax = plt.suplots()
df.plot(ax=ax)
```

But as I'm diving deeper the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35677767/understanding-matplotlib-plt-figure-axarr/35685864#35685864) threw me off. Specifically, I still have methods I need to call directly off plt, that don't apply to either a figure or an axis. Example:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df[['realgdp','trend']]["2000-03-31":].plot(figsize=(8,8), ax=ax)
ax.set_title('Real GDP & Trend')
ax.set_ylabel('Readl GDP')

plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

If I try to call xticks(rotation=45) off ax or fig I get an error that neither ax nor fig have an xticks method. The solution I have above works, but I don't understand why.

When I type `plt.xticks(rotations=45)`, where does that information get sent? Why does the comment in the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35677767/understanding-matplotlib-plt-figure-axarr/35685864#35685864) that "when you use the functions available on the module pyplot you are plotting to the 'current figure' and 'current axes'" not apply in this case? Why do I need to call off plt directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plt.xticks()` only works on the "current" ax. You should use `ax.set_xticks()`, `ax.set_xticklabels()` and `ax.tick_params()` instead.

`plt.xticks()` is a rather old function that is still supported, mimicking similar matlab code, born in a time when people were only plotting onto a single plot. The newer functions are more general with more options.

In short: you don't need to call `plt` directly, you are invited to use the `ax` functions instead. When calling `plt.xticks()`, it gets rerouted to the currently active `ax` (often the last one created).

Comment: This filled in the missing dots for me. I was able to replace plt.xticks(rotation=45) with ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45). And now I can intertwine pandas and Matplotlib in a happy, sensical, object-oriented way. Thank you!